# Emacs python-mode file mode specification error

Tags: emacs, python-mode

I am using `GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2013-03-17 on MARVIN` on a Windows 7 Enterprise, SP1 machine.

I have tried to install `python-mode`via ELPA, but got the following message in the `*Compile-log*`:

```
Leaving directory c:/Users/my_user/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/python-0.25.1

Compiling file c:/Users/my_user/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/python-0.25.1/python-pkg.el at Wed Dec  9 08:15:52 2015

Entering directory c:/Users/my_user/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/python-0.25.1

Compiling file c:/Users/my_user/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/python-0.25.1/python.el at Wed Dec  9 08:15:52 2015

python.el:2779:1:Warning: Unused lexical variable `inferior-python-mode-hook'

python.el:4033:1:Error: Symbol's function definition is void: format-message

Compiling no file at Wed Dec  9 08:15:54 2015
```

Needless to say, `M-x python-mode` does not work on my `.py` file. In the `messages` buffer, I get the following:

```
Eager macro-expansion failure: (void-function format-message)
let*: Symbol's function definition is void: format-message
```

Whereas if I find the file anew, that is reported in the `minibuffer`:

```
File mode specification error: (void-function format-message)
```

**EDIT**

Although the original source of error may remain unclear, instead of going through `ELPA` I just followed the link posted in the answer, unpacked the archive in a suitable directory, and followed the instruction to activate the package. `python-mode` works just fine.

Comment: What version of Emacs are you using? (Check with `M-x version RET`.)

Comment: @Chris the command returns: `GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2013-03-17 on MARVIN`.
Will update question as well, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK python.el is built-in. i.e. no need to install the elpa-version.

Alternatively there is python-mode.el, providing a different python-mode, available from melpa or

https://gitlab.com/groups/python-mode-devs

Comment: The reason why I went on trying to install stuff from ELPA is because the basic mode - whatever it may be called - was not working.
In other words, I got an error message when finding my_script.py, and `emacs` was set in general mode.

Comment: I just went to your suggested link and downloaded to a folder, added the path as instructed et voilà :-)
Works like a charm!